# Why my application installed from cydia can't access core data?

Tags: iphone, core-data, cydia

I wrote an application which uses sqllite via coredata. It works fine on simulator or being installed on a device from xcode. 
I need to provide a test version of application to some other people like ui designer or QA. I decided to use Cydia for this task. Although it installs fine it can't initialize persistentStoreCoordinator: addPersistentStoreWithType returns nil and error object reports Cocoa Error 258 (it looks like NSFileReadInvalidFileNameError, am i right?).
What's wrong with cydia installation? Did anybody encounter such issue?
Is there any other way to distribute an application among a group of people (not for everyone in appstore)?
I suppose ad-hoc is not my case since they all live in different places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another solution if you want to distribute your application : the AdHoc method.

This links describe how to set up the environment for beta tester : 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1669/how-to-host-a-beta-test-for-your-ios-app

All you need from their iPhone is there UDID (Universal Device ID) and you can get this ID from there : http://www.innerfence.com/howto/find-iphone-unique-device-identifier-udid

The only one restriction is you can only manage 100 beta tester / year

(I know that's not the main subject, but why accessing SQLite using core Data ? This link can help : http://www.raywenderlich.com/tag/sqlite)

Comment: +1 He needs to use the approved method for beta testing. In answer to your last question, he is probably using Core Data with an SQL store.

Comment: Thanks, for answer. I for some unknown reason thought that AdHoc Apps can be installed only via developer's Mac. Fortunately i was wrong. AdHoc works for me pretty well now.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use core data without a problem. I've noticed that most of the time when it isn't working, the file permissions of the jailbroken device have screwed up.

Try this:
If you have SBsettings installed, open it (slide the menubar) and tap the "More" icon. From there, tap the "Extras" bar. Here, tap "Fix User dir permissions".